# Swift cancel button to different controllers

Tags: ios, swift, navigation

I'm coding a simple app with swift and I'm stuck at the following point, I have two Controllers that lead to another one, and when I click on the cancel button, it always lead to the root Controller, no matter from where I come.

I have a first controller (`UIViewController`), that go to the Navigation Controller of my target Controller (the one from which I would like to go back to the right calling Controller).

I have a second controller (`UITableViewController`), which go directly to my target Controller.

Here's the code of my Cancel button:

```
// MARK: - Navigation
    @IBAction func lendingCancelButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways
        let isPresentingInAddLendingMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController
        if isPresentingInAddLendingMode {
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else if let owningNavigationController = navigationController {
            owningNavigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
        } else {
            fatalError("the LendingViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
        }
    }
```

If I correctly understood (you could then correct me if I'm wrong, I would learn something), it's testing if the ViewController that's presenting my target ViewController is a NavigationController.

So maybe that, as the second Controller (my `UITableViewController`) is not going through a NavigationController, so the last one calling my target view with a NavigationController is always the `UIViewController`.

Don't hesitate to tell me if it's not clear enough (too many times the word "Controller" in my post) or if you need additional code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I finally found a way to make it working.

My tableViewController was embedded into a NavigationController. I removed it (since I could do without it, according to my need). From this View Controller, I draw a segue that "Show" my target view.
From my other ViewController (this one is embedded into a NavigationController), I draw a segue put that present modally my target view.

With the code provided in my initial post, it's working.
The only thing I didn't understand is why the NavigationController from my TableViewController was likely to cause it not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
if let navigationController = presentingViewController as UINavigationController {
    navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
} else if let viewController = presentingViewController as UIViewController {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
    fatalError("the LendingViewController is not inside a navigation controller.")
}
```

If i understood you want to use `dismiss` when you find a `UIViewController` and to pop the navigation when you find a `UINavigationController` right?

Comment: Hi, not really, in fact I want to dismiss when I came from a controller presenting my view modally. However I have two different controllers presenting it. One through a navigation controller (modally) and another directly (presenting in push mode).

Comment: Okay so when you came back to one View from two different other Views you want to execute two different things right?!

Comment: In other words, I have two views going to one. What I'm looking for is to get back to the right one (the one that has presented my target view).

Comment: Ohh I finally understood, there are a lot of things you can do!
One thing you can do is to pass a variable to the next ViewController that specify the previous view, so you can know what view you should represent when you want to come back and present in the way you want

Another thing that you can do is to embed all the viewController you have in a navigationController, you can simply use the command navigationController.popViewController to go back to the right view and have a perfect control to your application flux